# Change language in StarCraft v1.18

Tags: starcraft

I just installed the new free version of StarCraft from Blizzard, which comes with a new update to version 1.18

When I started the installer, it asked me for the language, and I picked "Italian", but now I notice that all the keyboard shortcuts are "italianized"!

Since I would not want to re-learn them all, is there a way to change language to English without the need to uninstall and then re-download the whole 1.60 GB package?

Also, if I **do** re-install, will it ask for the language again, or is that choice perhaps saved somewhere in the windows registry?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming you're on Windows for this.

You're looking at a 3-step process, based on what I can find [on the official forums](https://us.battle.net/forums/en/starcraft/topic/20753887519):

1. Uninstall the game.
2. Delete the registry key specified below (using regedit)
3. Reinstall the game. If you've deleted the registry key, you should be prompted for the language by the installer.

The registry key you should delete is the following:

> \HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Blizzard Entertainment\Classic Launcher\s1t

---

For Mac OS, you're still going to have to delete some files, see [this thread on the official forums](https://us.battle.net/forums/en/starcraft/topic/20754545655) for details on that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the language in the settings on the launcher and not whilst in game? Usually that option is on the launcher and it will download any additional files.

Comment: I would I do that? Clicking on the desktop link just starts the game. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: I don't think the Starcraft Brood War launcher has a language change option. I don't think there was an option to change the language post-install, either.

Comment: My mistake Brood Wars does not appear to be integrated with the BattleNet launcher like the rest of the games.